# Django: How to add created_at with nulls for old records?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm trying to add created_at field to a table with millions of records, and I don't want to add value to the previous records.

I have tried the following:

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
OR
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Still, it set the value to all records, not only to new ones.
How can I keep the old with nulls?

My database is postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto_now_add=True` automatically sets the fields value and it is not editable.
You need to remove the `auto_now_add` and set a default value. Best approach for that is:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=now)
```